# "A game Object can only be in one layer" error in OVR Script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game using Oculus Rift DK2 and Leap Motion.
I use Scripts named OVRVisionGuide.cs and OVRMainMenu.cs.

My errors are :

> A game object can only be in one layer. The layer needs to be in the range [0...31]
>   UnityEngine.GameObject:set_layer(Int32)
>   OVRMainMenu:Start() (at Assets/OVR/Scripts/Util/OVRMainMenu.cs:274)
>
> A game object can only be in one layer. The layer needs to be in the range [0...31]
>   UnityEngine.GameObject:set_layer(Int32)
>   OVRMainMenu:Start() (at Assets/OVR/Scripts/Util/OVRMainMenu.cs:274)

I don't know how to do :/ ?

Comment: Post the three lines codes on line 273,274 and 275. The code from OVRMainMenu.cs.

Comment: If you don't provide the source code, you limit the people who can answer your question to those who worked with this SDK and are familiar with it. Which will greatly reduce your chances of getting an answer.